# How can I display a RefinableString in PNP Search Results Template?

Tags: search, pnp, metadata

How can I display a RefinableString in PNP Search Results Template?

I've created the managed metadata field (RefinableString100), I have it mapped to my field in the document library and I've selected in the PNP results webpart as Selected properties. I've got the refinement panel working with the RefinableStrings, but for some reason I cannot display the RefinableString data in the results template. I want to show the Sections applicable to each of the items in the search results. I'm trying this with the following handlebar code in the template: {{slot item @root.slots.RefinableString100}}

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have the same problem, my refinable in the filters panel is ok, but impossible to display it in the template results. I have checked my slot name and added it to the property displayed. Have you find a solution ?